Chromatic Polynomial of Hamming Graphs
I'm trying to calculate the chromatic polynomial of different Hamming Graphs , especially $H(3, 3) = K_3 \times K_3 \times K_3$, so the Graph Cartesian product of the complete graph with three vertices. It has $27$ vertices and $81$ edges.  If possible, also for different Hamming Graphs $H(d,q)$ with $q \geq 3$ and $d \geq 3$.
Literature: In general it seems that not much is known about the chromatic polynomial of graphs that have been formed by the Cartesian product. Two special cases, $P_2 \times P_n$ and $C_3 \times P_n$ are known from Pfaff and Walker and Chia lists a few more special cases, namely $K_3 \times K_s$ and $K_4 \times K_s$. It seems to me that an analytical approach is, if even possible, very difficult and would rather belong to math.stackexchange.
Algorithms: The chromatic polynomial for $H(d, 2) = Q_d$ (being the $d$-Cubic graph) is listed here up to $d=5$, although no proof is given. $Q_5$ has $32$ vertices and $80$ edges. So my assumption is that it is performed by a deletion-contraction formula. I tried to to calculate $H(3, 3)$ on my computer, but after a couple of days I did not get a result and couldn't figure out how far the programm has come, e.g. SageMath does not seem to provide a progress bar for this function (which one can probably only guess anyway).
Questions:
1. Does the chromatic polynomial of $H(d, q)$ for $d \geq 3$ and $q \geq 3$ already exists and I just didn't find it?
2. Does it seem reasonable to calculate the chromatic polynomial of graph with $|V|=27$ and $|E|=81$ by a deletion-contraction-algorithm? Here is a thread about the complexity, but I'm not sure if for $Q_5$ a different approach was chosen which incorporates that it's a very symmetric graph, as the complexity would result in $O(2^{81})$ for $H(3, 3)$.

Probably, using dynamic programming and memoization might help.

$O(2^{81}) = O(1)$ ;))))))
